# jQuery plugin, function that operates on each jQuery object then executes final statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is it possible to write a jQuery plug-in that operates on each item in a jQuery object using this syntax:

```
(function ($){
 $.fn.extend({
  DoSomething: function(){ 
   return this.each(function () {
    //Do something to each item
   });
   //Run the general update
   update();
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

But then I want to finish the function call with a general "update" operation.

How would I go about doing something like this? it will be quite slow if I do the update after each operation, rather than at the end, but I'll be putting this code in a few places, so I was hoping **not** to separate this out into two calls: `$(object).DoSomething().update();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be what you are after, but:

```
(function ($){
 $.fn.extend({
  DoSomething: function(){ 
   this.each(function () {
    //Do something to each item
   });
   //Run the general update
   update();
   return this;
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Will execute your `this.each()` functionality and then your update() function.

Comment: haha. I think that's exactly what I want, guess I was almost there with the exception of where I was putting the return statement. Thanks!

Comment: actually, as it turns out, update is being called twice, even when there is only one item in `this.each()`, any clue why that might be?

Comment: hrmm... now I'm confused, but I moved it out to a function rather than being just a couple lines of code. It is now only called once. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Strange. Looks like update() get's called once here? http://jsfiddle.net/ZeBVu/ so maybe DoSomething() is called twice?

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
$.fn.extend({
  doSomething: function (eachProcess, whenDone) {
    var result = this.each(eachProcess);
    whenDone();
    return result;
  }
});
```

So you'd pass in the function to call for each item (`eachProcess`) and for completion (`whenDone`).

Comment: I actually have the whenDone() function defined within the plugin, so rather than passing it in, I can just refer to it in the doSomething.